# Visual Studio not detecting new class, need to close and open VS again

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

First of all, I can't add a new class from the template (Right-click folder -> Add -> Class). The list doesn't contain a class template. I add an interface and rename it a public class. But the newly added class is not recognized in other classes.
I need to close and re-open the project. While closing it asks for saving .sln file.

After a lot of googling, I found out that devexpress extension was causing such behavior. I am not using devexpress or any third-party extensions
I tried

- disabling all the extensions.
- Reinstall VS.

Both VS Community 2019 & 2022 have the same issue. I am sure it's something with project, new project seems to work properly.

Comment: this see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832807/visual-studio-is-not-recognizing-new-classes#:~:text=To%20check%20this%20you%20need,re%2Dbuild%20project%2Fsolution.) I hope it will help you with this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio is not recognizing new classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832807/visual-studio-is-not-recognizing-new-classes)

Comment: "While closing it asks for saving .sln file." That sounds wrong. Are you trying to add the file to the _solution_? You need to add files to a project. With very few exceptions, the solution should only contain folders and projects, but not files (and definitely not source files)

Comment: Do you have the right workloads installed in Visual Studio to support .NET?

Comment: @Muhammad Uzair Only restarting the VS helps.

Comment: @PMF While closing i get prompt to save changes to the following PROJ.sln, PROJ. Maybe it is the project file under that solution.

Comment: @James Croft I am not sure what you mean. All other project seems to work fine, only this project has a problem. This is a very old project.

Comment: Then maybe update the project? If it still uses the old project format, you should update it to SDK-Style.

Comment: @FazilKunhamed would you be able to update your question to include some screenshots of what you're doing and if possible, some code snippets of the solution and project file you're adding to that require you to close VS? 

I think this might help us understand this further.