# ImageUrl on Custom Control Design Time

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-controls

I have build a Custom Control with an ImageURL property.  At design time when I enter an image in the ImageUrl I get the following error message

Error Creating Control - AmazeDropDownList1'~/Image/help.png' could not be set on property 'ImageUrl'.

```
<myCompany:MyCompanyDropDownList ID="AmazeDropDownList1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/help.png">
</myCompany:MyCompanyDropDownList>
```

The code for my control is shown below:

```
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.ImageUrlEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [Description("Image_ImageUrl")]
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [UrlProperty]
    public virtual string ImageUrl
    {
        get
        {
            string str = (string)this.ViewState["ImageUrl"];
            if (str != null)
            {
                return str;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["ImageUrl"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I am inheriting from TextBox, below is my render method:

```
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Call the base class's Render method.
        base.Render(writer);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ImageUrl))
        {
            // Create and render a new Image Web control.
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            image.ID = "Image1";
            image.ImageUrl = ImageUrl;
            image.AlternateText = ImageAltText;
            image.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
```

I would really appreciate any help in fixing the error message.

Comment: I see you "yanked" from Reflector. :O)

Comment: Have you implemented a `RenderContents` or `AddAttributesToRender` method as appropriate?

Comment: What version of visual studios are you using?

Comment: 2008 and I have a render method I have got a RenderContents or AddAttributesToRender as I am inheriting from TextBox

Comment: Sounds a lot like a bug I had with the visual studios cache in version 2005. Try my answer below.

Comment: I agree with GenericTypeTea, you need to clear out the web cache. This is a frequent problem, especially with C# Web Site solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if Visual Studios is using an incorrectly cached version of your control?

You can try and clear the cache yourself. Instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista).

Or, you could try removing the control from the toolbox (if it's there), removing all the control references from the page (i.e. the `<%@ Register...` tags), rebuilding all, and then re-adding the control.

Final guess, reference the control within the Web.config instead of on the page:

```
<system.web>
 <controls>
  <add tagPrefix="my" namespace="myCompany.Controls" 
            assembly="myCompany.Controls"/>
 </controls>
</system.web>
```