# Visual Studio 2010 Pro, Prevent Debugging 3rd Party Controls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I want to prevent VS from attempting to debug code that is not mine. When I 'Step-Into' my code, VS tries to find resource files I don't have. I'm really not interested in viewing the 3rd party code  code.

How can I only step through my managed code?

Followed this without success:
[Restrict Visual Studio 2010 from debugging third-party DLL files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048585/restrict-visual-studio-2010-from-debugging-third-party-dll-files)

Also changed JIT debugging to Managed only.

Comment: Have you enabled "Just My Code"?

Comment: In Options -> Debugging -> General "Enable Just My Code" is checked.

Comment: Why don't you just use Step-Over instead?  That's what it is made to do.  Only use Step-Into if you actually want to debug the code in the method that is getting called.  Use Step-Out to fix accidents.

Comment: ahh, I'm learning C# so I want to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: What Hans suggests doesn't prevent you from knowing what is going on. If you end up in something that is not your code, just click "Step Out". I use this approach all the time. *Sometimes* I want to debug into framework code, but *most* of the time, I just want to see mine.

Comment: Since writing this I've started using breakpoints more and as you both say, stepping over the 3rd party control. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using breakpoints and step over.