# t4mvc, cannot resovle symbol "MVC"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

i just switched from vs2010 to vs2012, and installed t4mvc. now. all my links are stop working.

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Admin.Food.AdminAdded());
```

I will get cannot resolve symbol MVC.

```
@Links.Content.images.btn_save_changes_png
```

I will get cannot resolve symbol Links.

i have no idea how to fix it, pleaes help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure that T4MVC is generating its files? Try right clicking the .tt file and choosing 'Run Custom Tool', which should force the generation.

If the files are generated, you should be able to look at them to make sense of why they don't match your references.

Comment: I didnt do exactly what you told me to do. instead I have to uninstall then reinstall the T4MVC, then it regenerates those files again. oh,I have to delete those old generated files first.

Answer (score 0):

try clearing the VS caches and update to the latest build of ReSharper.

the caches are located at

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\VWDWebCache

and possibly here

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

REF:[How do you clear your Visual Studio cache on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista)

Below are listed some helpful links:

[MVC 3 Project Upgrade Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx)

[May be its a KNOWN ISSUE which has been RESOLVED](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-178681)