# Where is the cache file located in VS 2015's app directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm trying to clean and rebuild my solution in an attempt to fix another [debugging error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057856/dialog-box-in-vs-2015-claiming-debugging-is-disabled-in-web-config-file) but can't locate the for VS 2015 cache file. The solutions in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista) don't appear to apply to VS 2015 / Windows 10. Does someone know a more accurate file directory address?

Comment: Do you happen to know the directory on a non-Windows 10 computer? Have you tried deleting the temp folder?

Comment: @BlackFrog - Windows 10 not relevant.  It is version of VS you are running that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the `.vs` folder in the root of your project.

As it's a hidden folder you need to enable "show hidden folders" in explorer or whatever file viewing tool you use.