# How to remove cache from VS2015

Tags: android, caching, visual-studio-2015

I've a Windows Phone application to make but i've a big problem with cache...

When i make HTML change, i don't see the change when i open the windows phone emulator ...

I want to know if it's possible to delete this cache from visual studio 2015... I've looking on google, i've tried some answer but nothing give me satisfaction...

- Delete every file in the cache folder but my problem is always here...
- Clear solution
- Build

It's more simple with Android studio... Run - Clean and Rerun...

Okay ! I've finally find something good...... Finally...

[Where is the cache file located in VS 2015's app directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059450/where-is-the-cache-file-located-in-vs-2015s-app-directory)