# WebForm1 doesnt contain a definition for 'Context'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am new to C#. Just following simple examples from Kudvenkat tutorials. 
http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/calling-stored-procedure-with-output.html

Keep getting those errors and cannot understand what am I doing wrong?

My .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black; font-family:Arial">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Employee Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>        
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Gender
                </td>
                <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Salary
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>          
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>  
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my aspx.cs file `txtEmployeeName.Text`, `ddlGender.SelectedValue` and 'txtSalary.Text' have red underline that says `"The name .txt does not exist in a current context"`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


namespace adoDemo
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            //Read the connection string from Web.Config file
            string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                //Create the SqlCommand object
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddEmployee", con);
                //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //Add the input parameters to the command object
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtEmployeeName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddlGender.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", txtSalary.Text);

                //Add the output parameter to the command object
                SqlParameter outPutParameter = new SqlParameter();
                outPutParameter.ParameterName = "@EmployeeId";
                outPutParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
                outPutParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outPutParameter);

                //Open the connection and execute the query
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Retrieve the value of the output parameter
                string EmployeeId = outPutParameter.Value.ToString();
                lblMessage.Text = "Employee Id = " + EmployeeId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my aspx.designer.cs file:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace adoDemo {


    public partial class WebForm1 {

        /// <summary>
        /// form1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

        /// <summary>
        /// txtEmployeeName control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtEmployeeName;

        /// <summary>
        /// ddlGender control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ddlGender;

        /// <summary>
        /// txtSalary control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtSalary;

        /// <summary>
        /// btnSubmit control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnSubmit;

        /// <summary>
        /// lblMessage control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check designer file to see if properties were generated, if not delete and recreate this textbox

Comment: I have added the designer file. Sorry, but how can I see if properties were generated?

Comment: Its actually there, just recreate it clean then try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get this error due to and assembly caching problem because VS gets confused about what actually needs to be recompiled. Just [delete the cache items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520593/3796048) and recompile normally.

Take a look in the designer file and see if Visual Studio created an entry in there for the controls. Make sure you don't have another file somewhere with a similar declarations.

Many times, best way to fix this is to delete, re-create and re-name the form. Since, We're not supposed to edit the designer file ourselves.

Comment: I have recreate and renamed the form. I also cleared VS cache directory.
But it still underlined: txtEmployeeName.Text, ddlGender.SelectedValue and 'txtSalary.Text' have red underline that says "The name .txt does not exist in a current context" . I starting to hate this language:)

Comment: Thank you very much. What helped me is to completely delete and recreate the whole project and renaming every possible file. 
Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1"%>
```

It should be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="adoDemo.WebForm1"%>
```

`Inherits` should also contain the `namespace` name, in your case `adoDemo`