# Visual Studio not suggesting references any more

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 not suggesting to include references when adding new type. 
For example, in the attached image, `XmlDocument` is not recognized and I have to include the proper reference manually (add `using System.XmlDocument;`) although the assembly (dll file) is added as reference.
But, usually, VS provides a list of suggestions to include a reference or create new type.

How can I enable back this feature?

[image]

Comment: How did you manually include it? With a using statement? If so, show us your using statement.

Comment: Adding a "using" directive is not the same as adding a reference. You still need the corresponding assembly (dll) added as a reference. Are you sure you have the System.Xml assembly added as a reference to your project (look in the "References" node in the project node in the Solution Explorer window)

Comment: @SimonMourier System.Xml assembly was added

Comment: And everything else works? I mean is IntelliSence enabled?

Comment: @ErikŠťastný IntelliSence is working fine

Comment: You will have to spin the Repair/Reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok. I thought I'm missing something with the configuration

Comment: check your notifications in Visual Studio, I had this a couple of times and Visual Studio gave me the option to repair this part.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear your Visual Studio temp files - it can often get confused about project structures and require a fresh start.

First, quit out of VS completely and restart it. If the problem is still there, find your VS cache folder and delete it, and then do a rebuild.

[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista/520684) For help finding your cache folder,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear the MEF Component Cache.
The component cache is located at %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache.
Use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ClearMEFComponentCache) or delete the cache  manually.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + . which means (dot) over the word XmlDocument to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try in VS 2015 [Tools] --> [Options] --> [Text Editor] --> [C#] --> [Advanced] --> [x] Suggest usings for types in referenced assemblies (check this)