# Visual Studio Type is not defined

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Im working in a vb.net project for months. Today i started my computer and saw thousands upon thousands of errors, mostly `Type 'x' is not defined`. Searched through the web but couldnt find a thing that worked for me, this post being the most notable one: [How do you clear your Visual Studio cache on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista/520684) . Deleting .vs folder had no effect either.

Im using Visual studio 2015 on windows 10, and i pretty sure the problem is something about cache, since re downloading the project or reverting changes didnt worked, how can i fix this? I'm loosing my mind

Comment: Start looking onto references if something is broken or some path is missing.

Comment: Have you tried repairing VS2015? There should be that option in the "Add or remove programs" control panel (or whatever it is called now), perhaps under a "Modify" button.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for trying to help, it solved today bc it was a network error (as mentioned in my answer). Im sorry for it being internal stuff that you guys shouldnt have knowledge of

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it happened to be a network error in my workplace, so the program couldnt get the DLLs used.
Probably this question won't be much of a use to anyone, try the article that i mentioned in the question first, or deleting your .vs file:
[How do you clear your Visual Studio cache on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista/520684)

But it is worth noticing that a network error can be your problem too, so stay aware of that.