# Visual Studio 2013 Missing Convert To Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am managing an old web application which still has legacy code from Framework 1 (would you believe it), currently on Framework 4.0.

As and when I need to fix or upgrade a web page, I convert it to a web application web page by clicking "Convert to Web Application".

VS 2013 doesn't appear to have the same menu item. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

It's been moved to the 'Project' menu towards the bottom after selecting the project or folder:

[image: Convert to Web Application]

Sources: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806246/visual-studio-2013-web-forms-conver-to-web-applications

Comment: You can also select aspx/ascx files and the option is available. This is useful when you want to regenerate the .designer file, by deleting it and running the 'Convert to Web Application' command over the markup file.

Comment: This is not what I see - when I select a web site project in vs2013 the "project" menu switches to a "website" menu, which has no such option. I did find, however, that there is a mapping for it in the keyboard options, so it is still there somewhere! I mapped it to a key combination but got "The key combination ... is bound to command (Convert to Web Application) which is not currently available" in the status bar. :/

Comment: See this answer.  I suspect you're in a web site, and not a web application project.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735054/how-to-convert-asp-net-website-to-asp-net-web-application

Comment: There's a problem with converting an entire app.  We have an app which is a mix of CodeFile and CodeBehind (don't ask...).  I can't do just one file, and converting the entire project converts those which are CodeFiles as well.

Comment: when you are in a website, there is no project menu in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: RTFM - This was never available from a web site project.  You have to create a web application project first, then copy the web site project files to it... -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah @cchamberlain, but you have to understand the guys, it's not really intuitive to "Convert to Web Application" when you're already inside a web application. ;-)
Anyway I just wanted to add it's exactly the same thing under VS 2015, in case someone still has any doubt about it.

Comment: If you can't find this option, make sure you select the project node in the solution explorer first, then check the Project menu again. D'oh!

Comment: Update - In VS 2017 the "Convert to Web Application" is still listed under the VS Project menu as show above. Don't look for it in the project context menu as it is no longer listed there.

Comment: Roberto, A+ comment.  Just confirmed it exists in VS 2019 from the Project menu in the WAP project type.  Saved me from having to declare a whole lot of controls manually.

Answer (score -1):

Open your .sln file i.e. solution file

change the below lines
1) From ,Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, **Format Version 12.00**
   to, Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, **Format Version 10.00**

2) From, TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv**4.5**"
    To, TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv**4.0**"

Answer (score -3):

MSDN has a [walkthrough on converting manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Your link doesn't help much but thanks anyway. I still need to upgrade each page as and when I need to change it... so I use VS 2012!

Comment: Thanks, but the OP was asking about a specific menu item that appears missing in VS2K13.  The accepted answer indicates that it was simply moved to a different menu.