# Visual Studio 2013 Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013

I get a compilation error in my web page. I've just upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 Professional (version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1) from VS2010 (I still have VS2010 installed).

One of the webpages I'm developing is not running after the upgrade. The error shown in the web browser when running locally is:

> Compilation error with error code 1.
>
> Which is translated from spanish: **"Error del compilador con el código de error 1."**

I found more information about the error in Windows event viewer:

> Faulting application vbc.exe, version 12.0.20806.33440, stamp 52005857, faulting module kernelbase.dll, version 6.3.9600.16408, stamp 523d45f2, debug? 0, fault address 0x00011aa0

This error only happens with a single aspx page. I tried renaming it, creating a new one (with the same code), running with IIS Express, IIS Local, as administrator, in Chrome, IE11, FF... I also disabled my antivirus. But I always get the same error.

Other clases in the project are running correct, for example a lot of webservices I've deployed under the same project.

The project is a classical web project developed under .NET 4.0 with VB.NET.

Are there any solutions to this specific problem?

Comment: Try deleting `aspx.designer.vb` file and regenerate it by RightClick on aspx -> select `Convert to web application`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately I'm not able to convert to web application. I have two options: 1) Convert to Office Project 2) Convert to Sharepoint project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561982/visual-studio-2013-missing-convert-to-web-application

Comment: Thanks again. I converted to web application but I get the same error.