# Cannot access controls from code behind & cannot convert to web application ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, code-behind

I've had an ongoing problem in my asp.net website, where I cannot access controls from the .cs file. It gives me the error: control not in context or whatever it normally does.

**What's weird is that I have no designer.cs files or the option to convert to web application.**

I've tried right clicking my project name, my file names, and everything else, but I cannot find "Convert To Web Application." I'm using **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition** and the latest versions of ASP.NET and stuff. For example, I have the following code in my page:

`<asp:TextBox ID="AssignScreenName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Placeholder="Screen name"></asp:TextBox>` (It's for renaming yourself on your profile)

When in the `Page_Load` class of my code behind, `AssignScreenName.Text` will give me that error. I have to use `Page.FindControl("AssignScreenName")`, which doesn't let me convert to text and assign it to the profile.

Is there a way around this, or a way to fix it? (If you need anymore information post it in the comments, I'll try to check back here daily)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561982/visual-studio-2013-missing-convert-to-web-application ?

Comment: Page.FindControl("AssignScreenName") will work if you cast it to the correct type, i.e. "Page.FindControl("AssignScreenName") as TextBox"

Comment: Thank you, Sh1rts, that's a temporary solution. And David, I tried your solution, but "Convert To Web Application" isn't in the Project menu (Which I can only access by clicking the label that says "Solution 'ProjectName' (1 Project)". It turns into "Website" if I click anything else.